# How to center the center circle?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering, alignment

How to center the center circle (CSS only)?   *[Assume latest CSS3 browser support.]*

Must maintain v/h centering when parent w/h changes dynamically.

Would the experimental CSS Box Model spec help here?

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/VdJFa/5/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.parent         {display: table; 
                margin: 50px auto;
                background: lightgray;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;}

.middle         {display: table-cell; 
                vertical-align: middle;}

.circle         {margin: auto;
                border: solid 10px blue;
                border-radius: 50%;
                opacity: 0.3;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;}

.circle .circle {width: 15px;
                height: 15px;}
```

Comment: i dont think i've ever seen someone format their css like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your middle container, appropriate `padding`,It will help bringing the content to the center.

You can achieve the same by giving a `left` i.e. making your `.middle` as:

```
.middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:10%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Also, you have to give your child `div.circle` a specific `width` and `height` combined with `border-radius` to align it and to give it a shape of circle.

And finally you need to play with the margin of the inner circle to align it.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/VdJFa/14/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply. margin: auto; horizontally centers both circles. Is there a dynamic way to set the inner circle? Rather than (margin-top: 8px;)? Thanks again. http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/LC5QL/

Comment: instead of giving margin-top:8px, you can give margin:7px, but that's same thing. see, most of your other classes use static width, so its very troublesome. besides, the static values you are using are very small, i guess, you can go ahead with that

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the perfect solution, but it works for me. The centering tags that SHOULD be used didn't change anything here, so I hope anyone will come with a better solution.

```
.circle .circle{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the small circle within the big one simply use this on `.circle .circle`:

```
margin-top: 7px;
```

You align the inner circle horizontally using `margin: auto`. To get this thing vertically centered calculate the top margin as the size of the outer circle is fixed too. Its basically like this:

```
( outer circle (height) - inner circle (height + 2 x border) ) / 2
( 50 - 15 + 10 + 10 ) / 2 = 7.5px
```

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/zkNHz/)

### First answer

**Solves to center the small circle within the big one even if the big one gets bigger**

If the the size of `parent` increases, the big circle should scale and the small one should stay small and in the middle. Is that correct? Then this could work - try to change the parent's width:

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/UhBLC/]

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="tiny_circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    display: table; 
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: lightgray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.circle {    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tiny_circle {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Both circle's w/h are static while **.parent's** w/h are dynamic.

Comment: @DRAGON I've updated my answer. Hope this is what you want. You can now change the size of parent but both circles are centered.

Comment: Yes. Your updated response is almost there. (margin: auto;) helped center things horizontally. Is there a dynamic way to set the inner circle vertically though - rather than (margin-top: 7px;)? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `place-items` of `grid`. The outer circle is defines as a grid here.

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 10px blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* Two lines below added */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.circle .circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```